# how to make recipes for gutenprint in yocto?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am new to Yocto. I have not found any documentation on how to create a recipe for this type of source code. Please do let me know.

This is link to the package [gutenprint repo](https://sourceforge.net/p/gimp-print/source/ci/master/tree/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is already supported by OE `http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/recipes/gutenprint/gutenprint_5.1.3.bb` ?

Comment: @Nayfe I think that repo is obsolete and https://layers.openembedded.org/ doesn't find any gutenprint recipes

Comment: "I have not found any documentation on how to create a recipe for this type of source code" really needs some details: how is this source incompatible with the documentation (and vast number of examples in Yocto sources) and what did you try?

Comment: so if you see the source code in the link its has Makefile.am to do make and make install to install it on a regular Linux machine. But I am finding ant good documentation on how to create a recipe for yocto to build this package